# JSF 2.0 FileNotFoundException

Tags: jsf

getting the below exception when accessing `http://localhost:8081/ReportGeneratorJSF/`
com.sun.faces.context.FacesFileNotFoundException: /login.xhtml Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource

I am using JSF 2.0

i have created a login.xhtml inside WEB-INF folder which is using templates of header.xhtml and footer.xhtml using basictemplate.xhtml

// login.xhtml

```
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/template/basictemplate.xhtml">
...
textboxs and submit button
...
</ui:composition>
```

// web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>ReportGeneratorJSF</display-name>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/login.xhtml</welcome-file>
      </welcome-file-list>
      <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
      </servlet>
      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Can you please provide solution for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem in your files, you need to place them like this :

```
WEB-INF
- faces-config.xml
- web.xml
login.xhtml
header.xhtml
footer.xhtml
...
```